# DataTables pagination buttons break with many pages

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

What could cause DataTables pagination to break like that (the Previous button and the pages numbers):

[image]

Also, when the number of page is too long, for example 14233, it is hidden inside the button.

How can I fix DataTable pagination to adjust correctly to the text in the button and also not make the "Previous" button go out of the button borders?

This is my sDom:

```
.DataTable({
    sDom: '<"row"<"col-10" B><"col-1"f><"col-1 r-0"l>>tip',
```

But nothing seem to fix that

Edit: I noticed that whenever I add the "disabled" class to the `ui` element of the "Previous" button, it fixes the issue, but how can I check what exactly is the thing in the `disabled` class that fixes it?

This is the HTML:

```
<table class="table text-md-nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="box-sizing: border-box">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
            <th>Col 4</th>
            <th width="20"></th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Kindly add the HTML as well as the DataTable's javascript.

Comment: I added the HTML, need to also add js soon

Comment: _"need to also add js soon"_ Kindly do. It's very difficult to make anything out of what you've provided so far.

Comment: I didn't add it because I was looking at other tables and all seem to have that issue, and it feels like someone put a style that override the buttons style because when I add the `disabled` class to the `Previous` button it fixes it (Not the numbers though). I need to then figure out what style is doing it, I don't think it's JS